# How to send .gz file as attachment from emacs using wanderlust?

Tags: emacs, wanderlust

I already found out to send attachments with wanderlust through `M-x mime-insert-encoded-file` and answering some questions. This works. But how can I send a `.gz` compressed file as an attachment?

`M-x mime-insert-encoded-file` inserts some cryptic string into the mail but when opening with Thunderbird, the text is in the body of the mail but there is no attachment.

Answer (score 0):

try `M-x mime-edit-insert-file`

this should produce something like the following:

```
--[[application/octet-stream; type=gzip; name="...gz"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="...gz"][base64]]
```

then, when you hit `C-c C-c` you should see your attachment "as usual"